# 'admin' $db always loads when I connect to MongoDB 3.6 using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am upgrading my node project to MongoDB 3.6 using mongoose. (I just NPM installed the latest versions of mongodb and mongoose, mongodb: 3.0.1, and mongoose: 5.0.1).

Regardless of the database name I pass in with my connection string, whenever I run a query that used to work for my project 
e.g.

```
configModel.find({type: 'settings'}, function (err, data) {...})
```

I now get an authorization error "MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command... $db: 'admin'"

This is the connection function I am currently using. I have also tried using mongoose.createConnection with the same result.

```
var options = {
  autoReconnect: true,
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  poolSize: 10
};

mongoose.connect(connectionString, options, function(err, db){
  ...
});
```

connectionString is in the format:

```
mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@[atlas.mongo].mongodb.net/<DATABASE_NAME>
```

This also gives me the same result

```
mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@[atlas.mongo].mongodb.net/<DATABASE_NAME>?authSource=admin
```

I am able to connect and query my database using Studio 3T with either of the connection strings above, so I think something is going wrong in mongoose.

Any ideas?

Comment: You didn't properly authorized the user. Are you on localhost or a cloud hosted solution ?

Comment: Cloud. 
It seems like an issue of getting to the right db -- using the 'intelliShell' on Studio 3T I can manually specify the db I want and execute any query with no problem. However in my app, despite specifying a different <DATABASE_NAME> in my connection string, I am always connected to the 'admin' db.

Answer (score 2):

just read that mongodb for node will have a fix for this in version 3.0.2. [link to Jira thread](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1286)